# ORA-01001 Invalid cursor error

Tags: oracle, cursor

I have written two database procedures in Oracle that are using multiple cursors. The problem faced is that while the procedures are getting executed without any errors in 98% of the cases, for few cases, the error - ORA-01001 invalid cursor is being thrown.

Since the problem occurs at runtime, it is getting difficult to identify the cause. I am unable to replicate the scenario wherein the procedure throws the error.

As per my understanding, since 98% of the cases are executing both the procedures without any problem, I don't think the cause is due to invalid Open-Fetch-Close commands.

Any idea what could be the possible reason for the exception being thrown?

I am adding a sample code:

```
CURSOR curWork(vCaseId VARCHAR2) IS
    SELECT w.X_WORKFUNCTION_ID
        FROM table_case c, table_queue w
        WHERE c.id_number = vCaseId
         AND c.CASE_CURRQ2QUEUE = w.objid;

CURSOR curPart(vCaseId VARCHAR2) IS
   SELECT p.x_part_number, p.X_FAULT_CATEGORY, p.X_FORW_GRP_ID
        FROM table_case c,  table_mod_level m, table_x_part_forw_grp p, table_part_num n
        WHERE c.id_number =vCaseId
         AND c.CASE_PRT2PART_INFO =m.objid
         And m.part_info2part_num=N.OBJID 
        AND N.S_PART_NUMBER=P.X_PART_NUMBER;

PROCEDURE UpdateAddressXY(vCaseId IN VARCHAR2, nStatus IN OUT NUMBER, vComment OUT VARCHAR2) IS
  bContinue boolean;
  nJobCode VARCHAR2(4);
  cnt number;

CURSOR curAddress(vCaseId VARCHAR2) IS
   select a.X_COORDINATE_X , a.X_COORDINATE_Y, A.X_XY_ORIGIN
   from table_address a, table_case c
   where C.ID_NUMBER =vCaseId
   and  a.objid =c.CASE2ADDRESS;       
rAdd curAddress%ROWTYPE;

--Get Dok Details
  CURSOR curDok(vCaseId VARCHAR2) IS
     select dk.x_dok_card_type, dk.x_line_src  from table_x_kat_dok  dk, table_case c
     where c.objid=DK.X_KAT_DOK2CASE
     and c.id_number=vCaseId;  

rDok curDok%ROWTYPE;

--Get Jobcode Details
  CURSOR curJCode(vWorkFunction Number, nForwGrpId Number) IS
       select x_code, x_code2, x_code3 
       from table_x_queue_jobcode 
       where X_WORKFUNCTION_ID=vWorkFunction
        and X_FORW_GRP_ID=nForwGrpId;

rJCode curJCode%ROWTYPE;

rPart curPart%ROWTYPE;
rWork curWork%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN

  bContinue := true;
  -- get Part details
  OPEN curPart(vCaseId);
  FETCH curPart INTO rPart;
  IF curPart%NOTFOUND THEN
    CLOSE curPart;
      bContinue := FALSE;
      nStatus := CONST.cError;
      vComment := 'Part Details Not Found | UpdateAddressXY';
  END IF;
  CLOSE curPart;

  -- get Work details
  OPEN curWork(vCaseId);
  FETCH curWork INTO rWork;
  IF curWork%NOTFOUND THEN
    CLOSE curWork;
     bContinue := FALSE;
     nStatus := CONST.cError;
     vComment := 'Work Details Not Found | UpdateAddressXY';
  END IF;
  CLOSE curWork;
  -- get Addess details
  OPEN curAddress(vCaseId);
  FETCH curAddress INTO rAdd;
  IF curAddress%NOTFOUND THEN
   CLOSE curAddress;
     bContinue := FALSE;
     nStatus := CONST.cError;
     vComment := 'Address Details Not Found | UpdateAddressXY';
   END IF;
   CLOSE curAddress;

--get Dok details  
   OPEN curDok(vCaseId);
FETCH curDok INTO rDok;
IF curDok%NOTFOUND THEN
    CLOSE curDok;
    bContinue := FALSE;
    nStatus := CONST.cError;
    vComment := 'Dok Details Not Found | UpdateAddressXY';
END IF;
CLOSE curDok;


--get Jobcode details  
 OPEN curJCode(rWork.X_WORKFUNCTION_ID,rPart.X_FORW_GRP_ID);
FETCH curJCode INTO rJCode;
IF curJCode%NOTFOUND THEN
    CLOSE curJCode;
     bContinue := FALSE;
     nStatus := CONST.cError;
     vComment := 'Jobcode Details Not Found | UpdateAddressXY';
END IF;
CLOSE curJCode;

if   bContinue then

 --job code

if ( Not (rDok.x_line_src is null OR rJCode.x_code3 is null OR upper(rDok.x_line_src)='DOK') ) then
    nJobCode:= rJCode.x_code3;
elsif (rDok.x_dok_card_type is not null and  rJCode.x_code2 is not null and ( substr(rDok.x_dok_card_type,1,1)='v' OR substr(rDok.x_dok_card_type,1,1)='V')) then
    nJobCode:= rJCode.x_code2;
 else
    nJobCode:= rJCode.x_code;
End if;


select count(CASE_ID) into cnt  from table_x_cu_address_jobcode where CASE_ID=vCaseId;
 if cnt=0 then
 Insert into table_x_cu_address_jobcode(CASE_ID, X_JOB_CODE,  X_COORDINATE_X,  X_COORDINATE_Y,  X_XY_ORIGIN)
 values(vCaseId,nJobCode,rAdd.X_COORDINATE_X,rAdd.X_COORDINATE_Y,rAdd.X_XY_ORIGIN);
 else
 Update table_x_cu_address_jobcode 
 set X_JOB_CODE=nJobCode,
 X_COORDINATE_X=rAdd.X_COORDINATE_X,
 X_COORDINATE_Y = rAdd.X_COORDINATE_Y,
 X_XY_ORIGIN=rAdd.X_XY_ORIGIN
 where CASE_ID=vCaseId;
 end if;
END if;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF vErrorMsg IS NULL THEN
        vErrorMsg := TO_CHAR(SQLCODE) || ' - ' || SQLERRM || cCRLF || ' | UpdateAddressXY';
    ELSE
        vErrorMsg := vErrorMsg || ' | UpdateAddressXY';
    END IF;
    nStatus := CONST.cError;
    vComment := vErrorMsg;

    insert into xxx(dat,seq,msg)
    values(SYSDATE,71180,vComment ||'@' || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);

End;
```

Comment: Can you show us some code ? could it be that you're not closing the cursor therefor having more opened cursors than `MAXOPENCURSORS` ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade -  I have added the code. Please check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to close the same cursor twice.
See:

```
IF curPart%NOTFOUND THEN
    CLOSE curPart;
      bContinue := FALSE;
      nStatus := CONST.cError;
      vComment := 'Part Details Not Found | UpdateAddressXY';
  END IF;
  CLOSE curPart;
```

If `curPart%NOTFOUND` then you close the curPart and afterwards (after the `end if`) you try to close it again.

If you want to stop in case that `curPart%NOTFOUND` then either use a if-else structure or [raise_application_error](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#i1871), if not- then just remove the `CLOSE curPart;` command from the `IF curPart%NOTFOUND ... END IF;` block